# what does 言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

A manga character says this to someone who told him to `やめろ`:

> なんで **やめろ**まで言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ!!

Is that `言われなくてはならない` and if it is, how can it be part of a question (with "nan de")? I don't really understand this sentence at all.

Comment: Are you sure about your citation? `やめろまで` sounds quite awkward, and has a smell of Japanese written by a non-native. Usually, it would be `やめろとまで`.

Comment: Does not sound awkward to me.

Comment: I hardly think that a character who would say 言われなくちゃなんねェ would know or care about that と。

Comment: oldergod, Paul Richter: I see, language geniuses.

Comment: @sawa anytime !

Comment: @Flaw I am not interested in discussing personal things here or in the chatroom, and the chatroom does not look much interesting. But if you are interested in discussing things about Japanese with me as you did before, there is no problem with that. If you doubt the validity of my answers, that is fine. I know that you are not among the people who claims (fantasy) things that even a native Japanese' do not know.

Comment: As Flaw would say: みんなさん、リラックスしましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand that やめろ is a really raw/strong/rude way to say "Stop (it) !" so I won't translate it to keep the strong meaning. (Other answers are missing this important fact. The speaker does not complain about being told to stop, but the way he is being told to stop.)

With your context, this sentence would mean: Why do you have to go this far by telling me やめろ. (ie: You could have been more gentle, a softer way to say this blabla....)

```
なんで sets the question.
やめろまで up to "やめろ"
言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ splited is like this
言われなくちゃ: 言われなくては
なんねェ:　ならない
んだよ: のです
いわれる: to be told
いわれなくてはならない => I have to be told
```

It's kind of *Why do I have to be told things this far/rude as やめろ*.

Comment: I'm curious why this was down-voted. If there's something wrong with it I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
なんで: why
やめろまで: up to "stop it"
言われなくちゃなんねェ  => 言われなくてはならない: 
  it needs to be said / [someone] needs to be told ("it won't do if not said")
んだよ!! => のですか: is it?
```

thus:

```
 Why does "stop it" even need to be said!?
```

The sentence itself does not define who is being told やめろ、so if the person being told やめろ says this as you indicate, it would mean:

```
Why do I even have to be told to stop?
```

If the other person is doing something that the speaker doesn't like, but he/she doesn't stop until told to by the speaker, the same thing would mean:

```
Why do you even have to be told to stop?
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching on Google, I found [this](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/tubomi3737/29896855.html) and [this](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/tubomi3737/30447174.html), so I'm assuming this is from Naruto:

> ...
>
> カカシ「ま！お前らは忍者学校に戻る必要もないな」
>   Kakashi: "Meh! There's no need for you lot to return to Ninja school."
>
> ...
>
> カカシ「……そう 3人とも… 忍者をやめろ！」
>   Kakashi: "...Yeah, the three of you... Quit (training to become) ninja!"
>
> ...
>
> ナルト「なんでやめろまで言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ!!」
>   Naruto: "Why must you go so far as to tell us to quit!"
>
> カカシ「どいつもこいつも 忍者になる資格もねェガキだってことだよ」
>   Kakashi: "Every single one of you, you're brats who're unqualified to become ninja!"

---

Here's a breakdown of that sentence:

> なんで やめろまで 言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ!!
>   Literal translation: "Why [must you/do you have to] go so far as telling us 'quit'!"

`なんで` means "why".

`やめろ` is quite strong, it could be an imperative of "quit!" or "stop!".

`まで` can mean "as/so far as" as well as "until, till doing".

`言われなくちゃなんねェ` is a more colloquial and more emphasized form of (the already colloquial) `言われなくちゃならない`, which is `言われなくてはならない`. `...言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ`, `...言われなくちゃならないのよ！` or `...言われなくてはならないのよ！` all mean "Why must you to go so far as telling us 'quit'!".

Comment: your translation makes sense but i'm still confused about why "iu" is conjugated that way...

Comment: @ogicu8abruok `iw-are-naku` = "SAY-PASSIVE-NEGATIVE".