# Meaning of なってねェよ?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **なってねェよ** when used in this context:

Speaker A: 何すんだ！！コイツはおれの仲間になったんだ！！

Speaker B: **なってねェよ！！！**

Answer (score 2):

Speaker B is saying that they have not become friends.

Speaker B: なってねェよ！！！

is

Speaker B: なっていないよ！！！

in more normal conjugation and spelling.

For more on ねェ, see [Clarification on 人の夢は終わらねェ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23137/clarification-on-%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A2%E3%81%AF%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%AD%E3%82%A7) ,  [what does 言われなくちゃなんねェんだよ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/what-does-%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%AD%E3%82%A7%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%88-mean/4480#4480) ,